# I can only store the one student details to the local storage.How can i store multiple student details using the same form in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

```
$("#smtbtn").click(function(){

    var username = $("#username").val()
    var email = $("#email").val()    
    var phone = $("#phone").val()
    var textcalendar = $("#text-calendar").val()
    var age = $("#age").val()
    var pic = $("#pic").val()
    var address = $("#address").val()
    var m1 = $("#m1").val()
    var m2 = $("#m2").val()
    var skill = $("#skill").val()

var student= [username,email,phone,textcalendar,age,pic,address,m1,m2,skill];
localStorage.setItem("studentdetails", JSON.stringify(student));

var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("studentdetails");
var movies1 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);

console.log(movies1);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set to localstorage:

```
students[username] = 
[username,email,phone,textcalendar,age,pic,address,m1,m2,skill];

localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(students));
```

Get from localstorage:

```
var students = localStorage.getItem("students");

if (students) {
    students = JSON.parse(students);
} else {
    students = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another level, like this:

```
var students = localStorage.getItem("students");

if (students) {
    students = JSON.parse(students);
} else {
    students = {};
}

students[username] = [username,email,phone,textcalendar,age,pic,address,m1,m2,skill];

localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(students));
```

and then if you call `getItem` you will have an object of key-value pairs where the key is the `username` and the value is the `student` object.

EDIT

Testing the feature:

```
    var students = localStorage.getItem("students");

    if (students) {
        students = JSON.parse(students);
    } else {
        students = {};
    }

   console.log(students);

    students["ha"] = ["ha", "haha"];

    localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(students));
```

Comment: when page refresh details losses

Comment: @midhunpc I forgot to stringify them, in my initial answer. Details should be successfully saved if you try the current version. If you still have problems, then I kindly ask you to create a JSFiddle.

Comment: if any idea about data store even page refresh

Comment: @midhunpc please create a JSFiddle about your current try. I can help you then.

Comment: @midhunpc please make sure you give me the JSFiddle link here when you have created it. I am sure that if I am still online here, then the solution will be found in a matter of minutes.

Comment: what i am trying to do is every student details who completes the form want to show their details in the  same page

Comment: even page refresh all the student details must be visible.if you got any idea to solve it.please help me

Comment: @midhunpc take a look at the keys you use at localstorage. You store a student as usernames, then store students, but you never load students.

Comment: @midhunpc Check out the code I have added to my answer. Run it in the console, reload the page, change the strings in the line of students["ha"] = ["ha", "haha"]; and run it again. You will see that the set of students is extended.

Comment: @midhunpc Unfortunately the JSFiddle you have shown is not working.

Comment: okay ur code is working.but in that code if we refresh page data losses ryt?

Comment: now its working in console.. i need to show all students in the page.how it possible

Comment: thank you i had done it with your help :) @Lajos Arpad